# Error running the project in Play Framework. Failed to listen to port :9000

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to run my Play2 project. When I type activator run in my terminal, it is loading and finally gives me this error message:

```
p.c.s.NettyServer - Failed to listen for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9000!
```

but I have not set anything on this port and I have no background processes in my terminal. Why this error appears to me?

Comment: Try to run it using `./activator "run 9876"`? It starts?

Comment: It started. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are able to start it using another port, it means that something is really using that port. It may be a different application or a previously stalled start of activator/play.

To find out what is using it you can use for example `lsof` in Linux:

```
$ lsof -i :9000
```

Once you find its pid you can stop that process.

If that port is used by another service and you really need it, instead of    providing always the port to the `run` command, you can try to add to your sbtopts (either in `~/.sbtopts` file or `SBT_OPTS` env var) this:

```
-Dhttp.port=9876
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a command to end all the processes on the port?

Comment: you can use `kill -9 <pid>`

Comment: what represents -9?

Comment: -9 is the type of signal being sent to the process, https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1332

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo lsof -i : <port>
```

then you get pId (consilder only java pId), run below command

```
kill -9 <pId>
```